# Prove that $S_n$ satisfies the following property: if $g \in S_n$, then $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are conjugate in $S_n$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

So I tried setting up an arbitrary $g$ such that $g(a_1)=b_1, ... g(a_k)=b_k$, and then I fizzled out. So I'm showing that for every a in $S_n,\ ag(a^{-1}) = g^{-1}$. I'm showing that they have the same cycle structure, but I'm not exactly sure how to show that in a rigorous, proofy type way.

Comment: Are you familiar with disjoint cycle representations?

Comment: So like, (a1a2a3...ak)(b1b2b3...bl)(c1c2c3...cm), etc.? Then the inverse is just, these written backwards. Does that conclude the proof?

Comment: Not quite. That doesn't show they are conjugate. There is a very useful fact about symmetric groups: the conjugacy classes are precisely the permutations of given cycle type. For this problem, it suffices to show that any two permutations with the same cycle type (which is the shape of the disjoint cycle factorization) are conjugate. You can do this by exhibiting an explicit conjugation which does the trick, and in order to do this it is recommended you know how conjugation affects a permutation's disjoint cycle factorization in explicit terms.

Comment: So that would be taking some arbitrary permutation, call it a, and showing that ag(a^-1)=g^-1?

Comment: You are missing some words in your sentence: "[...] there is a g [...]"

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $(a_1~a_2~\cdots~a_m)$ is an $m$-cycle. Then $\sigma(a_1~a_2~\cdots~a_m)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(a_1)~\sigma(a_2)~\cdots~\sigma(a_m))$. So,

$$\begin{array}{ll} & \sigma(a_{1,1}~\cdots~a_{1,m_1})(a_{2,1}~\cdots~a_{2,m_2})\cdots(a_{l,1}~\cdots~a_{l,m_l})\sigma^{-1} \\ = & \sigma(a_{1,1}~\cdots~a_{1,m_1})\sigma^{-1}\sigma(a_{2,1}~\cdots~a_{2,m_2})\sigma^{-1}\cdots\sigma(a_{l,1}~\cdots~a_{l,m_l})\sigma^{-1} \\ = & (\sigma(a_{1,1})~\cdots~\sigma(a_{1,m_1}))(\sigma(a_{2,1})~\cdots~\sigma(a_{2,m_2}))\cdots(\sigma(a_{l,1})~\cdots~\sigma(a_{l,m_l})) \end{array}.$$

Therefore, conjugation of something by $\sigma$ simply relabels the entries of the disjoint cycle factorization via application by $\sigma$. Suppose we have two elements with the same cycle type:

$$g=(a_{1,1}~\cdots~a_{1,m_1})(a_{2,1}~\cdots~a_{2,m_2})\cdots(a_{l,1}~\cdots~a_{l,m_l}) \\ h=(b_{1,1}~\cdots~b_{1,m_1})(b_{2,1}~\cdots~b_{2,m_2})\cdots(b_{l,1}~\cdots~b_{l,m_l}).$$

Then $g$ and $h$ are conjugate by any $\sigma$ which replaces the $a_{i,j}$s with $b_{i,j}$s.

In particular, $g$ and $g^{-1}$ in $S_n$ have the same cycle type.

Answer (score 1):

One way to show two permutations are conjugate is to show they have the same cycle structure, like you said. And it's pretty obvious a permutation and its inverse have the same cycle structure, since all we're doing is reversing the arrows—certainly nothing is changing about the structure. (see below) This might be messy to write out though.

[image]

Another common definition of conjugate is:  $x$ is conjugate to $y$ in $G$ iff there is some element $a \in G$ with $axa^{-1}=y$. So trying to show $g$ is conjugate to $g^{-1}$ amounts to finding some $a$ with $aga^{-1}=g^{-1}$, and this equation is readily solved for $a$.

Comment: is there some special trick to finding this a? I mean if a is arbitrary and g is arbitrary, can't I just say "let a be an element in G such that aga^-1=g^-1?

Comment: @Mik There are a number of issues with your comment. Firstly, when you say "if $a$ is arbitrary and $g$ is arbitrary," you are already fixing $a$ and $g$, so you can't afterwards say "let $a$ be an element such that ..." Secondly, it is not true that $aga^{-1}=g^{-1}$ holds for *arbitrary* $a$ or $g$. If you pick a $g$, it will not be true for just any $a$: you need to find the right one(s). That this equation does not hold generally should be "obvious." Thirdly, your comment does not invoke the structure of $S_n$ at all, so it must be wrong: there are groups where inverses *aren't* conjugate.